# Illegal character in path - C#, reading in xml

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to read xml into SQL and get an error at the "ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");" line,
any hints as to whats wrong?  Thanks

```
tring connectionString = "Data Source=MyServer\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable sourcedata = new DataTable();
        ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");

        sourcedata = ds.Tables[0];

        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconn))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("user_id", "user_id");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("upload_date", "upload_date");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("userAddr", "userAddr");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("serial_no", "serial_no");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Mfgr", "Mfgr");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("model", "model");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("description", "description");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("type", "type");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("code", "code");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("comments", "comments");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("qty", "qty");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("condition", "condition");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("location", "location");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("price", "price");
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Upload";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourcedata);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");` should be `ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");` - either use a string literal or escape the backslash via `\\`

Comment: -1ing this questions seems quite harsh. Clear question. Necessary code included (a bit more than needed but not excessive). Seems like a great question to me.

Comment: try this way : ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `C:\test.xml` is being read as `C:(tab character)est.xml`. Put a @ in front of your string: `@"C:\test.xml"`, or escape it with `"C:\\test.xml"`.

9 times out of ten, you'd get an error message along the lines of 'illegal escape character' when you make this mistake and it would be a lot more obvious what's wrong, but in this case it just happens to be legal.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had tried the "\\" but it worked fine with @

Answer (score 4):

Try escaping '\' symbol:

```
ds.ReadXml("C:\\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");
```

\t is seen as a horizontal tab character, unless you escape it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Changing this:

```
ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");
```

with

```
ds.ReadXml("C:\\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `\`, e.g.: `ds.ReadXml("C:\\test.xml");` or `ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that your \ character will need escaping. At the moment it is being read as `\t` which is a tab character and invalid. You want either:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");
ds.ReadXml("C:\\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a @ before your string:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");
```

This is called a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope your xml file format is correct .You just use  **ds.ReadXml(@"C:\test.xml");**
Insteaed of **ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");**